# Display Warning Message at Click Event of Cancel Button of Ribbon

Tags: ribbon

I want to display a warning message whenever user clicks the Cancel button on the ribbon of EditForm.aspx
OR
Hide/Remove the Cancel button from the Ribbon.

Both solutions are most welcome.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to hide look at this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff408060.aspx). In your situation definition should looks like this one:

```
 <CustomAction
     Id="RemoveRibbonButton"
     Location="CommandUI.Ribbon">
    <CommandUIExtension>
      <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.DocLibListForm.Edit.Commit.Cancel"/>
      </CommandUIDefinitions>
    </CommandUIExtension>
  </CustomAction>
```

**Small tip**: to quickly find button's id you can use inspect html tool in your favorite browser, inspect whole button (it will be html `a` element with id `Ribbon.DocLibListForm.Edit.Commit.Cancel-Large`), remove `-Large` postfix and this is your id in most situations. If button is more complicated, you can find it by this html id in `cmdui.xml` file, which contains definitions for all ribbon elements.

**edit:**
If you want display warning, you need replace default button with your own and with your own javascript handler:

```
 <CustomAction
     Id="RemoveRibbonButton"
     Location="CommandUI.Ribbon">
    <CommandUIExtension>
      <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.DocLibListForm.Edit.Commit.Cancel"/>
      </CommandUIDefinitions>
    </CommandUIExtension>
  </CustomAction>
  <CustomAction Id="2C9619A8-CCD8-4984-909C-2C1B7FE794E4"
                Location="CommandUI.Ribbon" >

    <CommandUIExtension>
      <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.DocLibListForm.Edit.Commit.Controls._children">
          <Button
                Id="E6DF7DBA-AC35-4ABA-9A12-4C87DAECA8BE"
                Sequence="20"
                Command="ConfirmClose"
                Image16by16="/_layouts/$Resources:core,Language;/images/formatmap16x16.png" Image16by16Top="0" Image16by16Left="-248"
                Image32by32="/_layouts/$Resources:core,Language;/images/formatmap32x32.png" Image32by32Top="-448" Image32by32Left="-288"
                LabelText="$Resources:core,cui_ButListFormCancel;"
                ToolTipTitle="$Resources:core,cui_ButListFormCancel;"
                ToolTipDescription="$Resources:core,cui_STT_ButListFormCancel;"
                TemplateAlias="o1"/>
        </CommandUIDefinition>
      </CommandUIDefinitions>
      <CommandUIHandlers>
        <CommandUIHandler Command="ConfirmClose"
                          CommandAction="javascript:if(confirm('Are you sure?')){SP.UI.ModalDialog.get_childDialog().close();}"/>
      </CommandUIHandlers>
    </CommandUIExtension>
  </CustomAction>
```

Button definition I copy from `cmdui.xml`, but replace with custom close command.
**note:** this code replaces **all** close buttons on all document libraries, if you want limit it only to specific list type or content type, use [`RegistrationId`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms460194.aspx) and [`RegistrationType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms460194.aspx) attributes on CustomAction.
 **note2:** if you have more complicated confirmation logic, place it in separate javascript file and refer from handler something like this:

```
CommandAction="javascript:myConfirmationFunction();"
```

Comment: @ZakirHC if the answer was the solution, please mark as answer

Comment: To display warning message box is a priority, kindly reply if any one has a solution, thanks.

Comment: @ZakirHC, please refer to my update

Comment: Thanks Kai for your kind help !!! Your efforts are appreciated

Comment: Hi Kai, can u explain few things here
1. <CustomAction Id="2C9619A8-CCD8-4984-909C-2C1B7FE794E4">
What Id is this, how do we get it?
2. <Button Id="E6DF7DBA-AC35-4ABA-9A12-4C87DAECA8BE"
What button Id is this, kindly explain and how to get it?

Comment: This ids is simply unique strings, you can use any other more meaningful names for you, such as `My.Namespace.Ribbon.Custom.Actions`. The only rule it should be unique.